# NLP: Calculate text time to read

Tags: python, nlp

I need to calculate estimated reading time for a few hundred Word documents. I couldn't identify a method to do so in common NLP libraries such as `spaCy` and `nltk`.

Any hint?

Comment: Reading time is very varying from one individual to the next; not to mention from one type of document to another. For instance, I read a lot of novels and a lot of scientific papers daily; I'm much much faster when I read novels than when I read scientific papers. The way Kindle does it, I think, is simply measure the reader's time since beginning of the book and extrapolate to the length of the whole book.

Comment: I know, but statistical models exist to estimate reading time depending on word count and text difficulty.